# Рассчитать наклон прямой

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Пробую построить угол в 45 градусов от значения `f`. Значение `f` это любое число например 120. Значение `х` это список из 200 значений разной величины. Вопрос - как можно построить `ag = [ ]` равное 200 значениям под углом в 45 градусов (или начало на пару знаков, чтобы потом можно было продолжить высчитывая по предыдущему)? Пример на рисунке, какие данные дать не знаю под такой вопрос, не очень пойму что должен делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В качестве своего кода есть такое, но это не верно (ag - угол который копируется при движении по х, h это изначально два вычисленных значений - но на выходе угол скатывается вместо 45 градусов в 20-30 под конец списка `х`, чем дальше по 200-м значениям проходим):

```
h = [el[0] for el in h]
ag = (h[-1]*100/h[0])-100
```

Comment: формула прямой: `f(x) = m*x + b`. Для угла 45 градусов - значение `m = 1`, т.е. в этом случае формула упрощается до: `y = x + b`,  осталось найти смещение по оси `Y` (коэффициент `b`). Для этого достаточно знать координаты одной (любой) точки лежащей на прямой

Comment: Вы можете дать координаты (значения `x` и `y`) для одной (любой) точки лежащей на прямой? PS Вы задаете вопрос о точке в __двумерном__ пространстве, но описываете точку `f` __одной__ координатой (`например 120`) - что такое 120??

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov Вы поняли вопрос о двух координатах?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда какие координаты у точки f?

Comment: приведу аналогию - представьте радиопередачу об игре в шахматы - диктор говорит: `игрок 1 походил ферзем на клетку E` - Представили?? Вот приблизительно так выглядит точка `f` (120) в двумерном пространстве :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если я вдруг всё правильно понял, то `y` (или `f(x)`) через заданные точки на `x` и начальное значение `y` (или `f`) рассчитывается элементарно:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x1, x2 = 20, 100
n = 200
y1 = 120

x = np.linspace(x1, x2, n)
y = x - x1 + y1
y2 = y[-1]

plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')
plt.xlim((x1,x2))
plt.ylim((y1,y2))
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title(f'f(x) = x{y1-x1:+d}')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: f(x)]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120905/discussion-on-answer-by-crazyelf---).